# Facebook Graphi API - extended permission photo_upload

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Has anyone on here seen this error?

> Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#260) Modifying existing photos requires the extended permission photo_upload thrown in /site/root/sdk/fb-php/base_facebook.php on line 1106

I've looked all over the internet and i can't seem to time anything to help me solve this. I went to the permissions page and don't see a permission option for "photo_upload" all i see that is close is "user_photos".

I'm trying to accomplish someone being able to upload a photo to a Facebook group... i can get it to work if the user is an admin but i can't get it to work for a standard user.

Comment: I think photo_upload is a sub-permission of user_photos, and granting that should work for you, but i'm not sure how well the groups API works with photos :/

Comment: Welp doesn't that figure?... LOL soon as i posted this i stumbled upon my problem... My group is set so that regular users cannot make wall posts. This is something that is a must so i'll have to find another approach. I want to control posts to my groups wall through my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp doesn't that figure?... LOL soon as i posted this i stumbled upon my problem... My group is set so that regular users cannot make wall posts. This is something that is a must so i'll have to find another approach. I want to control posts to my groups wall through my app.